# from xbbg import blp works for equity but does not work for bonds

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

**from xbbg import blp** works for equity but does not work for bonds.

I use this pip library: https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/

I do the following imports.

```
import blpapi
from xbbg import blp
```

I then run the following test for an equity:

```
# this works
eqData = blp.bdh(
    tickers='SPX Index', flds=['high', 'low', 'last_price'],
    start_date='2018-10-10', end_date='2018-10-20',
    )

print(eqData)
```

This works and produces the expected dataframe.

I do exactly the same for a corporate bond:

```
# this returns empty
bondData = blp.bdh(
    tickers='XS1152338072 Corp', flds=['px_bid', 'px_ask'],
    start_date='2019-10-10', end_date='2018-10-20',
    )

print(bondData)
```

This fails (produces an empty dataFrame), even though the data exists.

Here is the result (an empty DataFrame):

```
getting bond data...
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Also note that i can get the **BDP** function to work for bonds.
why can i not get the **BDH** function to work ?

Answer (score 1):

it appears as though the start date (year) was after the end date.
ie. change **2019** to **2018**.

```
start_date='2019-10-10', end_date='2018-10-20'
```

corrects to

```
start_date='2012-10-10', end_date='2018-10-20',
```

This produces the expected dataFrame.